# Symfony2 functional test - check table contents

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I have only ever used things like `contains()` in my assertions, so I'm not sure how I'd go about something as complex as this.

Let's say I have an array of expected answers - in this case it's YES, YES, NO.

So that means effectively, for the first and second question I'd expect to see `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>` inside the third `<td>` and for the third question I'd expect to see it inside the fourth `<td>`.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-curved">
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Item</th>
        <th width="60%">Description</th>
        <th width="10%">YES</th>
        <th width="10%">NO</th>
        <th width="10%">NOT APPLICABLE</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">1</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Check cargo is secure and undamaged.</td>
        <td class="report-centre success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">2</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Is all cargo accounted for.</td>
        <td class="report-centre success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">3</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Is all cargo checked by customs.</td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

How should I go about writing a test for this? Is it hard to iterate through the `<tr>`'s programatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I don't Symfony at all, but here's an answer that uses pure PHP DOM; it needs $values as an array with either 'pass' (to skip this `<tr>`) or an index of which column should have the `glyphicon-ok` class on it:

```
<?php
$data = <<<DATA
<table class="table table-curved">
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Item</th>
        <th width="60%">Description</th>
        <th width="10%">YES</th>
        <th width="10%">NO</th>
        <th width="10%">NOT APPLICABLE</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">1</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Check cargo is secure and undamaged.</td>
        <td class="report-centre success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">2</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Is all cargo accounted for.</td>
        <td class="report-centre success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="report-table-inner report-centre">3</td>
        <td class="report-table-inner">Is all cargo checked by customs.</td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
        <td class="report-centre danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
        <td class="report-centre"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
DATA;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$values = ['pass', 2, 2, 3];
$idx = 0;
foreach($xpath->query('//tr') as $tr) {
  if ($values[$idx] != 'pass') {
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $td = $tds->item($values[$idx]);
    if ($td instanceof DOMNode && $td->hasChildNodes()) {
      if (FALSE !== strpos($td->firstChild->getAttribute('class'), 'glyphicon-ok')) {
          echo "Matched on ", $tds->item(1)->textContent, "\n";
      } else {
          echo "Not matched on ", $tds->item(1)->textContent, "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  ++$idx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you TML. I really appreciate this.

Comment: The Symfony2 DomCrawler thing might make some of that manual DOM tree crawling easier; can't really say for sure.

Comment: Answered using Symfony Crawler [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868369/unsure-how-to-write-a-symfony2-functional-test-check-table-contents#answer-31961494)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at the documentation page about Testing and DomCrawler component:

- [Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html)
- [The DomCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

There are very simple methods which can filter html or xml content.

Comment: I have looked at this but it's very confusing.

Comment: Answered using those references [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868369/unsure-how-to-write-a-symfony2-functional-test-check-table-contents#answer-31961494)

Answer (score 2):

References :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-traversing

---

```
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PageTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testPage()
    {
        // create a client to get the content of the page
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/page');

        // retrieve table rows
        $rows = $crawler->filter('.table-curved tr');

        $statesColumnIndex = array(
            // 0 indexed
            'ok' => 2,
            'ko' => 3,
            'na' => 4,
        );

        $expectedValues = array(
            // 0 indexed, row index => [$values]
            1 => ['identifier' => 1, 'state' => 'ok'],
            2 => ['identifier' => 2, 'state' => 'ok'],
            3 => ['identifier' => 3, 'state' => 'ko'],
        );

        foreach ($expectedValues as $rowIndex => $values) {
            // retrieve columns for row
            $columns = $rows->eq($rowIndex)->filter('td');

            // check item identifier
            $identifierColumn = $columns->eq(0);
            $this->assertEquals(
                (string) $values['identifier'],   
                trim($identifierColumn->text())
            );

            // check state
            $stateColumn = $columns->eq($statesColumnIndex[$values['state']]);
            $this->assertEquals(1, $stateColumn->filter('.glyphicon-ok')->count());
        }
    }
}
```